# Can Capture One connect to a Nikon DSLR via WiFi?

Tags: nikon, tethering, wifi, nikon-d750, capture-one

My Nikon D750 camera has a built-in wifi module that allows it to be controlled via smartphone (shoot/view/download photos). Is it possible to connect my laptop to to the camera via wifi to automatically send photos to Capture One?

I am using a Mac, and ViewNX didn't work.

Comment: That depends. Is it necessary to tether with C1 or would it also be acceptable to use Nikon's software to tether and auto-import the pictures into C1?

Comment: C1 preferred. ViewNX didn’t worked on my Mac.

Comment: Why does ViewNX not work?

Comment: @flolilolilo there were some installer problems. Anyway now I'm working with Capture One and happy.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible in Lightroom, but not directly. The same method should also work for Capture One.

I use [qDslrDashboard](https://dslrdashboard.info/introduction/) to automatically download all pictures taken with the camera. Then Lightroom is configured to monitor and auto-import images from the download folder. I can control the camera via the computer, or shoot with the camera directly, and have images automatically show up in Lightroom. Capture One should also have the ability to monitor and auto-import from a folder.

qDslrDashboard works only for cameras with WLAN, which includes most Nikon, Canon and Sony cameras. It is free for Windows, Linux, and Mac. For iOS and Android, it costs 10€, but has more functionality than the Nikon app.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, **the best solution would be to troubleshoot your ViewNX**  <sup>(Nikon's proprietary software to connect to the DSLR)</sup> **installation**, because ViewNX seemingly offers the easiest solution for tethering.

As [@LuZel mentions in their answer](https://photo.stackexchange.com/a/101396/69369), **[qDslrDashboard](https://dslrdashboard.info/introduction/) seems to be a working third-party solution**.

---

The other tip I have is to try [Attaching an unsupported camera (Capture One help)](https://help.phaseone.com/en/CO11/Tethered-Capture/Camera-Settings.aspx#item2), which states that:

> When using an unsupported camera it may still be possible to use Capture One, **as long as you have a compatible capture utility for your specific camera model.** [...] Before connecting a camera model that’s directly supported by Capture One, deselect the appropriate Provider/Enabled Tethered Support (Mac/Windows) option in the Preferences first then restart the application.

So I guess that will not help you, either.

I found [one video where a Canon EOS 5D Mark IV is connected via the EOS Utility and then the files get imported into C1 via a hot folder](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Xyv6P5-0WVA) which basically shows the Canon-based solution for WiFi-connection with Capture One.

Comment: Your Google-Fu is too weak: qDslrDashboard supports wireless tethering. However, it seems to be quite fiddly with Snapbridge cameras.

Comment: @PeterTaylor included in my answer now. Thanks for noticing!